# Default working directory in SWI Prolog

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm having a problem with changing a directory in which I store `*.pl` files. The default one is located in my home folder. I can change working directory, either by using `working_directory` predicate or `cd` command in `swipl` interpreter. The thing is I have to do it every single time I run SWI Prolog, so I'm looking for a permanent solution. I tried to include those two solutions in `.plrc` file, which I created in my home directory but it didn't help.

I am a Mac OS X user, if that would be of any help.

Also, can you recommend any text editors for Prolog with multi-tabs support?

Comment: there are varous ways to load prolog files. Also with absolute path. have a look at `apropos(load).` and the surrounding predicates. I use Notepad++ with Haskell syntax highlighing.

Answer (score 3):

SWI-Prolog supports a per-user initialization file which, on POSIX systems such as MacOS X, is named `.plrc`. Simply create this file (if it doesn't exist already) on your home directory and add to it the line:

```
:- initialization(cd).
```

Regarding text editors with multi-tab and syntax coloring support for Prolog, try e.g. TextMate 2 (with the Prolog or the Logtalk bundles installed).